# Identification of two 3+1 pin SMD components - DC P39 and BD P44

Tags: mosfet, pcb-design, diodes, datasheet, surface-mount

I have these two SMD components, one with the nomenclature DC P39 and the other BD P44. I would like you to help me identify each of them, what they are, what they are used for, and provide the datasheet for each.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "BD" marking matches with a [BCX54-16](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Nexperia-BCX54-115_C126375.pdf) bipolar NPN transistor.

[image]

I linked the datasheet from Nexperia, but there are other manufacturers, like Shikues, with similar or identical markings.

The "DC" marking matches with a [BF620](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BF620_622.pdf) bipolar NPN transistor.

[image]

Again, the linked part is manufactured by Nexperia, but there are other producers.